# Is there a function in Kotlin to control the behavior of SearchEditText after the user clicks next on the virtual keyboard?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, focus, android-tv

**Description:**

I am trying to change the text colour of my EditText view when the user navigates away from the keyboard. there are two ways to navigate away from the keyboard to the screen. One is with the back button and one is with the next button.

I can handle the navigation change using the back button with:

```
tvSearchEdit?.setOnKeyboardDismissListener {
            tvSearchEdit?.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.lightBlack, null))
        }
```

But I cannot find a listener for dismissing the keyboard using the next button.

Looking for suggestions.

I do not want to override the button functions of the firestick controller. I know that is a solution.

I thought about writing a *setOnFocusChangeListener* for my "*tvSearchEdit*" but that would change the default behavior of focus changes on "*tvSearchEdit*" which is not what I want. let me know if there is a way to add to the onFocusChangeListener while preserving the default of the *leanback.widget.SearchEditText*

here is a picture of what the keyboard looks like:
[Fire Stick keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCJkD.png)

**What I'm trying to achieve!**

I have a search bar and the text colour changes to white when you navigate away from it which makes the text unreadable!

I'm trying to change the text colour to a translucent black instead.

Feel free to suggest a different solution if you think I'm trying too hard too handle the focus changes.

**Thanks in advance**

**Tech in use:** API Ver: 25, Fir Stick Ver: Fire OS 7.2, Language: Kotlin

Comment: Why not change the theme so the text color for unfocused state isn't white?

Comment: I'm new to Android and have not worked with themes yet I'll look into that.

Comment: I think you should because this is kind of an ugly hack to subvert the theming system that’s already in place to manage these color changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
val seListener= tvSearchEdit?.onFocusChangeListener
        tvSearchEdit?.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            seListener?.onFocusChange(v, hasFocus)
            tvSearchEdit?.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.lightBlack, null))
        }
```

this way I still preserved the widget implementation of the focus listener while adding my changes.
The trick was in saving *onFocusChangeListener* and calling it later.